# Thinest insulator between metal case and PCB?

Tags: enclosure, insulation

For a miniature product, I want the smallest possible product enclosure around the PCB. I figure I can get away with a 1mm thick metal sheet enclosure.

But I (probably) also need an insulator between the circuit board and the case, so nothing shorts out. What's the thinnest way I can make the inside of the metal case insulative? Paint? Powder coat? Paper?

Comment: What peak voltage (and max freq)? Any regulatory requirements? In what environment will it operate?

Comment: 5v USB used only occasionally. 3.3v logic. +/- 9v peak-to-peak low-current AC. --- FCC. --- Consumer electronics in everyday conditions; continental US.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(1 mm steel is *thick*!)

The isolation may not be required, since you're probably (S)ELV. Anyway, it's not going to cost you much space-wise. I wouldn't mess with paint sprays and such. Agreed, it's the thinnest, but I assume you can afford the thickness of a 0.1 mm PP (PolyPropylene, PP has very low water absorption) sheet?

Try to use only SMT parts, and mount them single-sided. PTH components will add at least 2 mm because of the pins sticking out at the other side. A **single-sided PCB** may be glued directly onto the PP sheet, which in turn you glue to the bottom of the enclosure. If you manage to do the wiring of the PCB single-sided as well you don't even need the PP insulation. It may be worth using a couple of 0 Ω jumpers to ease the layout.

You can save an extra couple tenths of mm by using a 0.8 mm PCB instead of the standard 1.6 mm. The thinner PCB is less stiff, but at the small size it's not a problem, and when glued against the enclosure it won't get any mechanical strain anyway.

Comment: Thanks! So even if a +5v and a GND are touching the polypropylene 1 mm or 2 apart from each other, it always presents high resistance?

Comment: Is this the stuff? http://www.goodfellow.com/catalogue/GFCat4J.php?ewd_token=CM7dFKFoZK4ZcBGXQsCsBQuSmkMuVI&n=GP87GKmxpjVzWuZgzmgL7e9WFHhIbT

Comment: @Evolved - Yep, that's the one. It mentions a roll width of 650 mm, though, and a roll may be 600 m worth (mine is), so that may be, er, somewhat much. You may ask them for a sample. The PP has a [volumetric resistivity](http://www.itwformex.com/pdf/formex_gatefold.pdf#page=1) of > 10\$^{15}\$, which is, er, pretty high. At these low voltages you're absolutely safe.

Comment: For playing (and better) "Mylar" [tm][literally] will do what you want as long as you do not mechanically puncture it. OHP (remember them) projection film is/was usually Mylar. That's a version of Polyester but is going to behave well enough for what you want.

Comment: @Russell - I guess a lot of plastics will be suitable, but I'm not a mechanical engineer, nor a chemical one, so I don't know them all. I do know that PP has about the lowest water absorption, and a high resistivity (I forgot the dimension ohm.cm in my previous comment).

Comment: @stevenvh - I have no problems with Polypropylene - it's good stuff in a number of ways. I just mentioned Mylar as it is better than many plastics in a number of ways and many companys will have a box of OHP material to hand.

Comment: @Russell - You're a bit vague about the benefits of polyester; I'd like to hear more about it. Feel free to add to my answer if you think it's useful for OP. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @stevenvh - I said Mylar, not Polyester. Mylar is A Polyester but Polyester is a large range of things - some vvv capable and others just quite good. And re vague - not at all. You are answering the questions around here. In this case anyway :-). Anyone wishing to avail themselves of my reccommemdation is welcome to key the name into you know where and they will be richly rewarded.

Answer (score 3):

Kapton tape as it's usually called, or generics found under "Polyimide Film Tape" is generally used for this sort of stuff - it's a good and thin insulator, but slightly expensive:

[image: https://www.flickr.com/photos/paintyourdragon/8298241344]

you could also just use normal (i.e. vinyl) electrical tape, which is a bit thinker, but also has the benefit of being "softer" and thus less prone to punctures/etc. which may result from a component leg or something sticking out, especially if it was "flush cut" which could result in a sharp edge

[image: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Rolls_of_adhesive_tape.jpg]

Answer (score -2):

Single sided PCB, Plastic, Sheet rubber, Bubble wrap, Duct Tape, Wood veneer, a few drops of silicon.

Comment: The melting temperature of silicon is in excess of 1400 °C. I suspect applying it will cause irreparable damage. It is also known to be a semiconductor rather than an insulator.

Comment: Another case of silicon/silicone confusion :) Contrary to popular belief, silicone valley is in California, but not the SF Bay area...